# ViewPagerAdapter update fragment when starting again

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have the following ViewPagerAdapter:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OwnerPendingBookingsFragment(), "Pendientes");
    adapter.addFrag(new OwnerConfirmedBookingsFragment(), "Confirmados");
    adapter.addFrag(new OwnerFinishedBookingsFragment(), "Finalizados");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

And one of the fragments that I use is like that:

```
public class OwnerConfirmedBookingsFragment extends Fragment {

private View myView;
private ListView booking_list;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private Toast toast;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private BookingList bookings;
private boolean isFirstTime;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (isFirstTime) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.owner_confirmed_bookings_layout, container, false);
        isFirstTime = false;
    }

    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isFirstTime = true;
    //Getting out sharedpreferences
    preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        new FindBookings().execute("");

}


private void setUpAdapter(){
    booking_list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.owner_confirmed_bookings);
    getActivity().setTitle("Nuevas solicitudes");
    if(bookings.getBookings().size() == 0){
        booking_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LinearLayout no_vehicles = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.no_confirmed_bookings_layout);
        no_vehicles.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i < bookings.getBookings().size(); i++){
            try {
                new setImageTask(i).execute(bookings.getBookings().get(i).getDriver_image()).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        adapter = new OwnerFinishedBookingsAdapter(myView.getContext(), bookings.getBookings());
        booking_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        booking_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int booking_line = bookings.getBookings().get(position).getBooking_line_id();
                Fragment booking_info = new OwnerPendingBookingInfoFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("bookingLine", booking_line);
                booking_info.setArguments(args);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, booking_info);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}

private class FindBookings extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String token = preferences.getString(Config.TOKEN, "");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage(getActivity().getString(R.string.finding_bookings));
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        if(bookings.getError() != 0){
            if(bookings.getError() == Config.JWT_EXPIRED){
                logout();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        getActivity().getString(R.string.session_expired),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                toast.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.find_pendings_errror));
                toast.show();
            }
        }else {
            setUpAdapter();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        bookings = DBConnect.getPendingBookingList(preferences.getInt(Config.IDUSER, 0), token);
        return "done";
    }
}
```

The first time I use it, all the fragments loads without any problem. But when I go to another activity and then return it doesn't update the data. I debug it and onCreate and onCreateView are not firing? 
I tried to remove the fragment when going to another activity but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I am assuming you are coming back to this activity, so the oncreate will not be fired as the activity was already there in the backstack, If you need to update your layout you can update it in either onresume or onstop. I prefer onstop because it gets fired less often than onresume.

Comment: @user2520215 Yes I am comming back to this activity. The problem here is that I only want it to be updated when I come back to this activity. When I am in this activity navigating from fragment to fragment I don't want them to be updated.